# how to extract image or video path from textarea?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having one textarea in which i will enter some text and this textarea will contain image path or video link.for eg:https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e514b017977ebf742a418cac697d8996?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG or any video link.

I want to extract image path or video path from text when i receive the value from my textarea on my controller.

My table which will store Textarea details:

```
Details:
Id,Description,image/videopath
```

so to store in my table i want to extract my image path or video path from my textarea.

Screenshot:[image]

Here in the above screent shot i am having one textarea which contain some text and link of my image with preview available below.

Below this i am having one submit button which will post this textarea value to my controller.

My View code:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("GetTextAreaData", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
        {
          <textarea id="details" name="textAreaDetails"></textarea>
                  <input type="submit" value="Finish" />
        }
```

My Controller:

```
 public ActionResult GetTextAreaData()
        {
            var textareaData=Request["textAreaDetails"];//get textarea details by name
            //Now how to extract image or video path from this???
        }
```

Comment: Did you try a regex to match URLs?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti:sorry i dont know how to use regex.

Comment: your are doing this on web application?

Comment: @MirzaDanishBaig:yes

Comment: @MariaPithia You can use Regex (if you don't know it, it is an invaluable resource to learn), or you can try parse it character-by-character. The latter is much more tedious and arguably harder to do than to simply learn regex

Comment: Additionally, you mentioned *image path or video link* - how would you know the content of the link without actually downloading it? Have you got some specific criteria? YouTube/Gravatar?

Comment: @RGraham:have you ever posted something on any linked group??.i want the same linkedin group posting functionality like in linked in when you want to post something in any group you need to enter title and description.so in description you can enter image path or video link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
var someTextWithOrWithoutUrl = ".... "

var match =  Regex.Match(someTextWithOrWithoutUrl , @"(https?://\S+)");
var url = match.Success ? match.Groups[1] : null;
```

This will will work for `http` as well as `https`.

Comment: yup i am getting image path succesfully but how to extract text ??

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltextarea.value(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: sir i want logic that will seperate my text and my image or video link from each other

Comment: If the unlikely case that your textarea contains only plain text, just replace the URL `textareaText.replace(url, "")`. However, if you want to preserve (or strip) HTML formating, I would suggest using the `HTMLAgilityPack`, which is available via NuGet. You have different options - for example: (a) Using an xpath expression you can find and remove the link expression `<a href...></a>` (b) You can convert the HTML contents using HtmlAgilityPack's method `InnerText()` to extract the pure text content and remove the plain URL.

Comment: @MariaPithia you had a tip to restart to solve the problem, don't expect people will write code for you (especially if you dump your requirements instead of your effort to solve your own problem).

Comment: @JimiLoe:there is no html formatting.its a simple plain text with url(either image or video)